# Is there any way to get the formula of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $u_0 = 100$, $ \alpha = -200 $ and $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N^*} u_n = u_{0} + n + \alpha \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{u_{i}}.$
Is there any way to get the formula of $ u_{n} $ ? or at least get an approximation? Convergence or divergence ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $u_{n+1}-u_n = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{u_n} \Rightarrow u_{n+1} = 1 +u_n + \frac{\alpha}{u_n}$.

From this recurrent definition it shouldn't be difficult to understand the behavior of $u_n$, depending on $\alpha$ and $u_0$. In your case, the sequence eventually diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Think if it converges, the limit is $ - \alpha $ no ?

Comment: That's one of the possibilities. If $u_n$ converges *to a finite limit*, it will converge to $-\alpha$ indeed. But the limit might not be finite, in fact in your case it is $+\infty$.

Comment: How did you know that in my case my sequence diverges to $ + \infty $

Comment: I would say it's not at all obvious that the limit is $+\infty$. Working in double-precision floating-point arithmetic, the actual sequence switches from positive to negative, not just once but eight times, before reaching a value greater than $200$ (the element preceding this is $-0.207575...$), after which of course it increases without limit. So understanding the behaviour of $u_n$ looks like a difficult problem to me.